# Change to the limitation of only using same domain addresses when programming email forwarding via API

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to script a email users migration that includes setting the forwarding addresses.  The documentation states:

> *Note: A valid value of forwardTo is an email address that has been already verified to be used as a forwarding address in the Google Mail account, or one that fulfills one of the following criteria:
>
> 1. It belongs to the same domain,
> 2. It belongs to a subdomain of the same domain, or
> 3. It belongs to a domain alias configured as part of the same Google Apps account.
>
> If the value of forwardTo doesn't adhere to one of these rules, setting up forwarding via the API will fail.*

Does anyone know if there's a trick to get around this, or if this particularly annoying restriction will be lifted?

Answer (score 1):

We've gotten around it by:

- Creating a Google group.
- Adding the forwarding destination as the only member of the group.
- ensuring the permissions of the group allow anyone to send to it.
- Setting the forward on the user mailbox to point to the Google Group.

So the user mailbox forwards to the group (internal) and the group forwards to the forwarding address (external).  A bit of a kludge but it does the job.

Comment: Sneaky, but a little too kludgey for me.  My number of users is probably at a point where I can deal with handling this manually.